# create php multidimensional array using while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

i have two tables category and images.i want create a multidimensional array like

```
$headings = ['heading 1', 'heading 2', 'heading 3'];
$images = [
    'heading 1' => ['image 1', 'image 2', 'image 3', 'image 4', 'image 5'],
    'heading 2' => ['image 1', 'image 2', 'image 3'],
    'heading 3' => ['image 1']
];
```

So how can i do that using php.

**Images table**

[image]

**category table**

[image]

Comment: title `careate` correct to `create`

Comment: what have you tried? It seems like you want us to develop the whole system for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804655/table-in-while-loop-side-by-side

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "select category.name,group_concat(images.image_name) from category inner join images on (category.id = images.category_id) group by category.name";
$table = mysql_query($sql);
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($table))
{
    $row['image_name'] = explode(",", $row['image_name']);
    $arr[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tool code you will need: `mysqli`. Now suppose you know it.

#### Solution 1

The slowest. Just fetch all the lines you need, then use a for loop to make it what you want.

#### Solution 2

Use `GROUP_BY` + `GROUP_CONCAT` function in sql.

I am in a hurry. So which do you like best, and do you need a further example?